# Django admin site callable field seems not working with python regex

Tags: python, django, python-re

I'm adding an additional column `repath` to the Django.admin site, according to the document, it oughts to work, but once I introduced `re` package to this function, things went wrong.
here's code sample:

```py
class InfoAddrAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'machineId', 'uptime', 'repath')
    list_filter = ('machineId',)

    def repath(self, obj):
        res = re.search(r"10\.1\d+\.\d+\.\d+", obj.ipaddr)
        return res.group()<-Exception comes from here
```

and the related Model is defined as:

```py
class RemoteAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    machineId = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    ipaddr = models.TextField()
```

A piece of text with lots of IP addresses(i.e. the result of command `ipconfig`) is stored in the `ipaddr` field, and that regex searchs for an IP with prefix like '10.1xx.xxx.xxx', which proved **working fine**.
The main error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Using debuging tools, the `res` is not a None, Just the opposite, it contains the correct value, I'm confused why django believes it is None.
Complete Error stack is avaliable at https://pastebin.com/8WUBdg1F

You may find some information from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: And what about the errors `KeyError: 'repath'` and `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: RemoteAddress has no field named 'repath'`. Those are the one resulting in the error message you show here. Are you mixing up `rpath` and `repath`?

Comment: There's only `repath`. Mistyped in the stackoverflow editor, the problem is still out there.

Comment: At what point do you get the error? When using the Django admin? If so, when exactly? When navigating to or through the app, when selecting the model, when editing an instance of the model in the admin, when adding a new instance? At what point(s) exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of an implementation of `def repath` that doesn't use the regex, and works for you?

Comment: When opening the Django admin page `InfoAddrAdmin` (just the page containing required columns 'id', 'machineId', 'uptime', 'repath'), error happens. If the `def repath` function is just a simple `return len(obj.ipaddr)`, the column 'repath' on the admin page will show the length of 'ipaddr' correctly.

Comment: I think you'll need to debug further. There likely is an ipaddr that doesn't match the regex. Wrap the regex line in a try-except block, print or log the exception in the except part, then return e.g. an empty string in the except part. In that case, you can see which ipaddr(s) in particular is/are causing a problem, while your app can continue.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add all `ipaddr`s to your question. But these might be too many, or shouldn't be public. You should, however, trim down your problem to a minimal set of `ipaddr`s (and other records) that still cause the problem.